# Reference value of another row (item) in list Validation Settings conditional formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-form, validation

Is possible to reference values of another row (item) in list Validation Settings conditional formula?

For example: I want to prevent the user to save a new item with same date of another existing item.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

You cannot reference values of another row (list item) in list Validation settings conditional formula (or calculated column formula).

[image]

**Source**: [Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

---

If you want unique value in column, across the list (for all users), you can "Enforce unique values" from column settings:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

Example of enforcing unique values on the list column:

User will see error message like below while saving the new list item when there is an existing list item with same column value:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Are you asking about the 2nd part in my answer, about having unique values in the column?

Comment: Yeah, regarding the example that I mentioned before (with the prevention of saving) . Thank you .

Comment: Check update answer with the screenshot

Comment: Please let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Oh this is nice. I really appreciate this.  but I get this alert "This column must be indexed to enforce unique values. Do you want to index this column?" and after click ok , i get error.

Comment: How many total existing items are in the list? You can first add indexing on the column by following this docs: [Add an index to a list or library column](https://support.microsoft.com/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Comment: ok I understand your concept. But I have multiple date columns per item. I want to implement tis logic on a specific date column, so i'm not sure that works.

Comment: Add the specific date column as index column, then set the specific date column Enforced unique column.

Comment: @Damian, it should work for you. Go to list settings and add indexing on your specific date column. Then go to column settings of that same specific date column and enforce unique values in it.

Comment: ok ok Thank you I appreciated . What do you think about that: I if I have a StartDate and EndDate column, i want,  if the duration coincides with the duration of another existing item dates, to prevent saving.

Comment: This cannot be done using the list validation settings or column settings.

Comment: You will have to use the custom solution for such validations as it cannot be achieved using SharePoint default validation settings. Custom solution depends on the version of SharePoint you are using, classic or modern experience, etc.

Comment: I use modern experience

Comment: You can customize the list forms using Power Apps and enforce such validations using Power Apps formulas. Check: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).